# Looking at Shabbat candles during Kiddush - why?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, kiddush

I've seen in the past that it is proper to look at the candles when saying "*yom hashishi*" during Friday night Kiddush. I think it is a Sefardi thing, but I can't find any reference to it in Yalkut Yosef, so could be wrong about that.

What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rama ([OC 271:10](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%90_%D7%99)) cites this practice from the Maharil. It is intended to heal the eyes from damage caused by taking large steps ([Brachot 43b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.43b.19)).